# Upload image using AJAX in Joomla 3.0 MVC

Tags: joomla-3.x, jquery, ajax

I am trying to upload a image using AJAX jquery in a Joomla MVC framework.

Below is the default.php which adds the below javascript script code

```
$('#icon-submit').on('click',(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var formData = new FormData($(this).closest('form')[0]));
  $.ajax({
    url: "index.php?option=com_jsmdownload&task=imageUpload",
    type: "POST",
    data:  new FormData(formData),
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData:false,
    success: function(data){
      alert(data);
    },
    error: function(){
    }
  });
}));
```

Below is the HTML code which contains a simple file box and a button

```
<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php'); ?>" method="POST" name="adminForm" id="adminForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" id="and_36x36" name="and_36x36">
  <input id='icon-submit' type='button' value='Next ->' />
</form>
```

Below is the PHP code in controller.php for the imageUpload task.

```
function imageUpload(){
  JFactory::getDocument()->setMimeEncoding( 'application/json' );
  print_r($_FILES);
  JFactory::getApplication()->close();
}
```

Once I select the file and click on the button the PHP function is not yet calling and I only see the below output

[image]

I dont know what I am doing wrong.  I want to get the selected file and upload them into the server and return back to the browser.

I referred multiple posts and cant able to find an answer.

One observation is that if I change the URL to a plain PHP file without importing the Joomla MVC then it works fine and I could see the below output.

[image]

Only problem is if I link to a component view then it doesn't called.  Need some advice to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add '&tmpl=component' to your URL in the AJAX call to return just the component output, not the whole page.

Change

```
url: "index.php?option=com_jsmdownload&task=imageUpload",
```

to

```
url: "index.php?option=com_jsmdownload&task=imageUpload&tmpl=component",
```

Try that and see if it works.

Comment: Sorry unfortunately adding `tmpl=component` also result the same and doesn't work.  One thing I noticed is if I set `contentType=true` then it calls the function correctly but the form values are not available.  Any more suggestions!!!

Comment: What about adding '&format=raw' too?

Comment: My bad... I forgot to add the hidden task field.  After adding the hidden box `<input type="hidden" name="task" value="imageUpload" /> ` in the default.php it started calling fine.  Thanks for your help.